# Maximize the trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

Find the maximum value of $$4\sin^2 x+3\cos^2 x+\sin(x/2)+\cos(x/2)$$ Please give some hints. I tried writing the angles in half-angles but it didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: given a function $f(x)$ what is the necessary condition for $f$ to have a (interior) maximum?

Comment: I know that this function has.

Comment: If you already came up to f'(x)=0 and computed f' you should put that into the question and make the question about the part you got stuck at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2f(x)=4(1-\cos2x)+3(1+\cos2x)+2\left(\sin\dfrac x2+\cos\dfrac x2\right)$$

$$=7-\sin2\left(\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac x2\right)+2\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac x2\right)$$

as $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2+A\right)=\cos A$

Set  $\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac x2=y$ and use [Second derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test)